# 500 Internal Server Error in spring boot post API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I'm trying to create a post API in a spring boot app but it's not working and i can't find the issue in the code

This is **service**:

```
  @Transactional
    public Invoice saveInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        Invoice newInvoice = invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
        return newInvoice;
    }
```

This is **the controller**:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Invoice> addInvoice(@RequestBody InvoiceDTO invoice) {
    try {
        Invoice newInvoice = invoiceService
                .saveInvoice(new Invoice(invoice.getSerialNumber(), invoice.getStatus(), invoice.getCreatedDate()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newInvoice, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

and this is the **model** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<InvoiceHistory> invoiceHistories;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Item> items;

    public Invoice(long serialNumber, String status, Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.status = status;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.isDeleted = false;
    }
}
```

But when I am running in in postman its returning 500 Internal Server Error

Update error message :

> , message=Cannot invoke
> "com.example.invoices.repository.IInvoiceRepository.save(Object)"
> because "this.invoiceRepository" is null, path=/invoice/save}]

where's the problem ?

Comment: How do you inject your dependency invoiceRepository in the service. You could fe. @Autwired it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your service class, how are you declaring and creating `invoiceRepository`?  If it's like this:

```java
private InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;
```

Then you need to add an `@Autowired`:

```java
@Autowired
private InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;
```

If you do have it `@Autowired`, make sure your service class is annotated with `@Service`:

```java
@Service
public class InvoiceService {...}
```

If you have that, make sure you aren't creating `InvoiceService` with `"new"` in your controller. Instead of:

```
private InvoiceService invoiceService = new InvoiceService();
```

or `"new"ing` it in a constructor,
use `@Autowire`

```java
@Autowire
private InvoiceService invoiceService;
```

Comment: To add to @bmargoat answer, also add `EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {com.PathToYourRepository})` in your main Spring boot application class!

Comment: EnableJpaRepositories disables some of Spring-Boot's functionality, SpringBootApplication alone is *probably* what he wants, unless otherwise specified.  This github issue has an interesting discussion: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8134